# OpenVPN failed connection / All TAP-Win32 adapters on this system are currently in use

Tags: windows, networking, adapter, vpn, openvpn

^^

i get this error if i would connect to any OpenVPN Network.

```
All TAP-Win32 adapters on this system are currently in use.
```

**Here is a Screenshot.**
-> http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=openvpn_failbhjde.jpg

**What i did before i post this?**

- Removing the TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS
- Reinstall openvpn
- Reinstall openvpn gui

I have the problem on two computers.
**Why?**

**My System:**

- Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit
- Normal Network Interface
- VirtualBox Network Interface
- TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS

All *legal*. All *up-to-date* (newest, stable version).

**Solution**

1. Download OpenVPN manually: http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html

:)

Comment: **Solution**

 1. Download OpenVPN manually: http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html

:)

Comment: Alternatively, if you use other software than OpenVPN package you may want to add TAP by hand, by downloading TAP-Windows from OpenVPN package ([link](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)), installing "TAP Utils" and then invoking "add a new tap virtual network adapter" (open start menu and just type "TAP" there)

Comment: You got this error is because there is not enough TAP virtual ethernet adapters in your system. **Here is the solution**: `Startup menu --> All Programs-->TAP-Windows-->Utilities-->Add a new TAP virtual ethernet adapter` . You can create several adapters if you need to connect multiple VPN at the same time.

Comment: Keep in mind to run any Shortcut from windows menu as "Run as Administrator", otherwise it will fail. Same apply to manual command line, the command prompt/Cygwin, any shell need to be started to run under Administrator rights.

Comment: had issue in win10 able to solved it : go to TAP-Windows\bin path (Ex:C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\bin) and run addtap.bat file

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I found a solution to this.  It's bloody witchcraft, but it works.

When you install the client, open **Control Panel > Network Connections**.

You'll see a disabled network connection that was added by the TAP installer (Local Area Connection 3 or some such).

Right Click it, click **Enable**.

The device will not reset itself to enabled, but that's ok; try connecting w/ the client again.  It'll work.

Comment: Thanks a million! I was tired of not being able to solve this issue.

Comment: On Windows 7 I didn't see a disabled connection. I ended up disabling the TAP installer and Re-enabling it.

Comment: The issue is off topic indeed - but thanks a bunch - works.

Comment: @Bradly Spicer, thanks. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: @BradlySpicer Worked for me on Windows 8.1, too.

Comment: Alternatively, if you use other software than OpenVPN package you may want to add TAP by hand, by downloading TAP-Windows from OpenVPN package ([link](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)), installing "TAP Utils" and then invoking "add a new tap virtual network adapter" (open start menu and just type "TAP" there)

Comment: Works on windows 10. Wow, what an easy solution!

Comment: You sir, are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are using the wrong version...

TAP-Win32 should not be installed on the 64bit version.  Download the right one and try again!

Comment: I'm using this version: `Installation Package (Both 32-bit and 64-bit TAP driver included): openvpn-2.0.9-gui-1.0.3-install.exe`.